# Incompatible pointer types sending 'UITapGestureRecognizer *' to parameter of type 'UIView * _Nonnull'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureAction)];
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

self.fullScreenImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];
self.fullScreenImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"family"];
self.fullScreenImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self addSubview:self.fullScreenImageView];
[self.fullScreenImageView addSubview:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

what's wrong with these code.
Xcode 7.0 gives this error :

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'UITapGestureRecognizer *' to
>   parameter of type 'UIView * _Nonnull'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `addGestureRecognizer` for adding a gesture to a UI object

```
// [self.fullScreenImageView addSubview:tapGestureRecognizer];

[self.fullScreenImageView addGestureRecognizer: tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: Please mark correct if you use the solution like my answer. Or please post your solution.

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureAction)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    
    self.fullScreenImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];
    self.fullScreenImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"family"];
    self.fullScreenImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addSubview:self.fullScreenImageView]; like your one

Answer (score 0):

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureAction)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

    self.fullScreenImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];
    self.fullScreenImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"family"];
    self.fullScreenImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addSubview:self.fullScreenImageView];
```

this is the solution. i found thanks @anhtu

Comment: When someone answers to your question, if you found that the answer is helpful you should accept the answer by clicking the green ticket near that answer. You shouldn't create a new answer.